# How to implement "not null" filter in angular js(Version 1)?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

How to find out the data which is not null using angular ui grid filter option.
I am getting the null values by typing null in search option of angular ui grid 
but on search about "notnull" in angualr ui grid I am getting the data from backend but it is not showing on angular ui.